# Use Universal Image Loader to load PHOTO_URI of contact

Tags: java, android, gridview, lazy-loading, universal-image-loader

Righ now i'm getting some problems following:

> 05-14 16:20:59.355: D/ImageLoader(31397): Start display image task
>   [content://com.android.contacts/contacts/281/photo_120x120] 05-14
>   16:20:59.360: D/ImageLoader(31397): Load image from network
>   [content://com.android.contacts/contacts/281/photo_120x120] 05-14
>   16:20:59.360: D/ImageLoader(31397): Cache image on disk
>   [content://com.android.contacts/contacts/281/photo_120x120]
>
> 05-14 16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397): URI:
>   content://com.android.contacts/contacts/281/photo/photo 05-14
>   16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI:
>   content://com.android.contacts/contacts/281/photo/photo 05-14
>   16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):     at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
>   05-14 16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):     at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
>   05-14 16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):     at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:385)
>   05-14 16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):     at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:417) 05-14
>   16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):     at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:360) 05-14
>   16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):     at
>   android.provider.ContactsContract$Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(ContactsContract.java:1982)
>   05-14 16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):     at
>   android.provider.ContactsContract$Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(ContactsContract.java:2013)
>   05-14 16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):     at
>   com.view.widget.ContactDownloader.getStreamFromContent(ContactDownloader.java:26)
>   05-14 16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):     at
>   com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:88)
>   05-14 16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):     at
>   com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:290)
>   05-14 16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):     at
>   com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:273)
>   05-14 16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):     at
>   com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:229)
>   05-14 16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):     at
>   com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:135)
>   05-14 16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>   05-14 16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   05-14 16:20:59.445: E/ImageLoader(31397):     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

I try to extend BaseImageDownloader and override getStreamFromContent(...) method in issue 564:
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/564
same:

```
@Override
protected InputStream getStreamFromContent(String imageUri, Object extra) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUri);
        if (imageUri.startsWith("content://com.android.contacts/")) {
            return ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(res, uri);
        } else {
            return res.openInputStream(uri);
        }
    }
```

but not success.

Please help me.

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running into the issue described (and solved) here: [Load Contact Image Into Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863879/load-contact-image-into-bitmap). For reference, the solution is to pass the URI of the contact itself to openContactPhotoInputStream(), not the URI of the contact's photo.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code its working fine for me. I hope it will also work for you as well...

```
public class BaseImageLoaderClass extends BaseImageDownloader {

public BaseImageLoaderClass(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

@Override
protected InputStream getStreamFromContent(String imageUri, Object extra)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUri);
    if (imageUri.startsWith("content://com.android.contacts/")) {
        // return ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(res,
        // uri);
        return getContactBitmapFromURI(context, uri);
    } else {
        return res.openInputStream(uri);
    }
}

public static InputStream getContactBitmapFromURI(Context context, Uri uri)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return input;
    // return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
}
}
```